# Can I change content based on the URL a user has accessed the site?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible for me to apply logic into my web application (currently a django web app) based on the URL the user has access the site from?

Basically, I want to offer a theme option that would change the site look and feel depending on what URL the user has access the application from.

So, as an example we have domain1.com and domain2.com, both are CNAMEs pointing to mywebapp.com. If you go to domain1.com I would like to site to be green, and if they go to domain2.com it would be red.

Comment: Consider the using the Sites framework for this, with the right amount of caching, of course. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 1):

Do a [request.get_host](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) check in base template and add different css accordingly:

```
{% if request.get_host == 'domain1.com' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/green.css">
{% else %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/red.css">
{% endif %}
```

Or do it this way. By default show site in green theme, but allow user to change theme on front end. And then store the chosen theme in session variable `theme`.

```
{% if request.session.theme == 'green' %}
```

Comment: Thanks Aamir Adnan, I will give that a try. I am assuming I could put some other logic in there so that it could query a database for domain one and determine the css file?

Comment: I think that is a bad idea as you have to query to database on every page load. Avoid hitting the database unless it is necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. I am trying to work out a way I can bring in a reseller style service. So that a Reseller can upload their own theme, and any of their clients will receive their uploaded theme.

Comment: You're fine querying a db for this info (theme, etc). If it becomes a bottleneck, you can cache the result.